# Pins on Pinterest link to 404 - yet link is valid

Tags: hyperlink, http-status-code-404, pinterest

this is a really strange one.

I've set up a bunch of pins on Pinterest linking through to our services which all work fine. Then I decided to do the same on our blog articles (we use Wordpress), yet everytime I click the link (and I've done this on different computers) the link goes to a 404 page on our site. However the link is valid and if you right click the pin and open in new window it opens fine: pinterest.com/pin/105342078755648946

I have contacted Pinterest who are next to useless. I have also tried different browsers, different computers and different Pinterest accounts.

I can't see any weirdness in my htaccess files causing this so I'm a little stumped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found this when I was searching for the same issue - so though it's an old question I thought I'd answer for anyone else who is searching!

My client was using a really old version of WordPress, when I upgraded to the latest version it fixed the issue. After a bit of digging it turns out you have to be on WordPress 1.5.2 and beyond in order to fix it - as they applied the fix in that update.